# Can anyone tell me where to find the older Visio shapes and templates?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I've just installed Visio 2013 and can't stand the look of the shapes for systems architecture (servers, workstations, databases, etc). I remember Visio diagrams using 3D shapes with a rounded, colourful look that gave the diagram some personality. The new shapes are accurate, but have all the charm of a cardboard box.

Can anyone tell me where to find the older Visio shapes and templates?

Answer (score 3):

Found them, thanks to http://www.nogeekleftbehind.com/2013/08/17/download-even-more-free-visio-network-stencils/

Microsoft provides these as downloads:

Microsoft Exchange 2010 Visio Stencil:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6977

Lync Server 2010 Visio Stencil 
...?id=20891  (I can't post more than two links)

I haven't tried loading these into Visio 2013 yet, but my understanding is that the file formats for Visio are stable from Visio 2003 forwards so it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an older version of Visio you can copy the stencils onto your new system. Just put the stencils in your **My Shapes** folder.